# How to read raw content of data-* attribute using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes

Maybe I am missing something, but I use `data-*` attribute, namely `data-content` with such entries like "apple", "cow", etc. Suddenly I was hit when I set my `data-content` with **string** "null" (I checked using Chromium HTML is:

```
<p class="text" data-content="null">null</p>
```

But when I read `data-content` using jQuery:

```
text_elem.data('content')
```

I get null value, not "null" string.

So my question is, how to read it in raw form, so I could get "null" string exactly as it is in HTML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get `null` instead of `"null"` because jQuery has for some reason decided to parse `data-` attributes as JSON when fetching using `.data()`.

To get the raw data, use `.attr()` instead. This will be faster, and it doesn't make a copy of the value into `jQuery.cache`, which is very often unnecessary.

Basically, only use `.data()` for `data-` attributes if you ***need*** the data stored in `jQuery.cache` and if you're alright with it being parsed as `JSON`.

Comment: Thank you very much both of you. Now, the tough time to select one to accept :-) Judging who needs points more...

Comment: @greenoldman: Don't sweat it. I don't need the points until they come up with a points-for-beer program. :-D

Comment: Please note that this is **not compatible** with fields that have their data stored using `data` method programmatically. It will really return the value of the attribute, not necessarily the data of de underlying data property.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to read it in the raw form you would need to use `.attr` instead of `.data`. Because that is what `data` api does it parses the content of the data attribute (ex JSON --> object, numeric string value to number etc...).

```
text_elem.attr('data-content');
```

Or you could use dataset (Not supported in older browsers) with the DOM element.

```
text_elem[0].dataset.content; //this will return a string
```

Comment: I remember that was a alternative of `.data()`...except `.attr()`, but can't remember which was it...

Comment: @HellBaby With newer browsers you can use dataSet with the DOM element. If that is what you meant?

Comment: Thankfully IE finally supports `.dataset` in version 11. Wasn't sure if they'd very get there.

Comment: @cookiemonster yeah in 11 its always IE a catch.... and you keep on always writing _not supported in older browsers though it is mostly IE the culprit._ :)

Comment: @PSL I don't remember it's name but sure wasn't dataSet - it was something that I saw like a month ago on this website(with fiddle attached in which he proved that data sucks cause you can't set/get data information correct). But in any case: setAttribute/getAttribute should be faster than attr IMHO

Comment: @HellBaby Yes that is right `get/setAttribute` has to be faster since there is no extra jquery wrapper over it... since jquery internally uses that only.. So....

Answer (score 0):

The `.find()` method could be use to search an XML document for the element name specified.  For the HTML document, if you want to access the attribute you must use the `.attr()` method.